# user permission definitions rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I thought I had this figured out but apparently not.  I'm trying to allow a user to edit one of their models, but prohibit them from editing other users' models.  To accomplish this I'm using the before_action in the model controller:

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

The problem (I think) is within my 'correct_user' definition.  If I do this def (and I've done many other similar versions) it won't allow anyone to edit anything and redirects all back to root_url.

```
def correct_user
      @user = current_user.model
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
```

But when I try something like this below, which seems more correct to me, every user can edit every model which is also not what I'm after.

```
def correct_user
     @model = Model.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.model
    end
```

I should mention there is a has_one, belongs_to association between the user and the model.  The user has_one, and the model belongs_to the user.  I read all of the ruby documentation and still don't understand where I'm f-ing up.

Can anyone explain what I should be trying that I'm not?  Or can you please point me towards some literature that maybe I haven't been able to find?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: `@model = Model.find(params[:id]); redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user == @model.user`. You can also try `Model.find_by(params.merge({user: current_user}))`

Comment: Thanks, the first version worked like a charm.